# Spring java config to invoke a public non static method of a singleton class with private constructor

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-framework-beans

I am working on changing a spring project to springboot and changing to java config from xml.
I have a singleton class with a private constructor, in the original xml the non static methods are invoked as such:

```
<bean id="myClassBeanId" class="com.myproject.dao.MyClass">

<bean id="daoservice" factory-bean="myClassBeanId" factory-method="createMyStaticVariable">
```

The objective is to somehow invoke the "public non static method" of a class with a private constructor to initialize the static variables of the same class in spring java config.
Could someone please tell the java config equivalent of the above xml config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
@Bean
public MyClass myClass() {
MyClass.class.getConstructror().makeAccessable () ;
return MyClass.class.getConstructror().invoke() :
} 
@Bean
public DaoService daoService(MyClass myClassBeanId) {
return myClassBeanId.createMyStaticVariable():
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the equivalent code, however, running this gives exception: No qualifying bean of type 'com.myproject.dao.MyClass'. Since MyClass has a private constructor, not sure how to define the 'MyClass myClassBeanId' bean. Could you please further help with this.

Comment: You will have to call the private constructor via reflection by calling `makeAccessable` first. I've added the pseudo code. This is what xml config processor does internally, I think.

Comment: Thanks again. For the time being made it work by adding a static variable of MyClass and adding getInstance method to return that. Been trying with reflection but no luck so far, will update once reflection too works. Not sure if either approach has any advantage over the other.